# Selenium and Python 3 – unable to find element

Tags: python, selenium

First off, apologies for a commonly asked question. I've looked through all the earlier examples but none of the answers seem to work in my situation.

I'm trying to locate the username and password fields from this website: http://epaper.bt.com.bn/

I've had no problems locating the "myprofile" element and clicking on it. It then loads a page into an iframe. Here's my problem. I've tried all the various methods like `find_element_by_id('input_username')`, `find_element_by_name('username')` etc and they all do not work. Would appreciate if someone could point me down the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first: (you should switch to iframe)

```
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_login")
```

then you can find your elements. For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("input_username").send_keys("username")
```

for moving out of iframe:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```